# Number of fonts used in Powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2013

Is there away in Powerpoint 2013 to identify how many different fonts are being used over multiple slides?

People are creating bizare looking presentations with fonts that seem to constantly change from one slide to the next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an exact count, but here how you can get a list of the fonts a presentation is using:

- On the **Home** tab, in the **Editing** group, click the down arrow next to **Replace** and choose *Replace Fonts*.
- This will open the **Replace Fonts** dialog box.
- The upper of the two list boxes tells you which fonts your presentation wants (a `?` next to any of the fonts indicates that the font isn't installed).
- Click the down arrow, and count the entries in that list box.

[image]